# Shell script with vimdiff command in Java source code gets stuck when run on Git bash

Tags: java, bash, shell, process, git-bash

I have a shell script with vimdiff command in my Java project.

OS: Windows

On GitBash, when I run the vimdiff command directly, it works fine and generates the result.

**Command that works fine on GIT BASH terminal:**

```
vimdiff file1.log file2.log -c TOhtml -c 'w! result.html' -c 'qa!'
```

But, when I try to run my test in the Java project, it gets stuck for a while and nothing is printed in the console. Not sure why.

**My shell script vimDiff.sh within the Java project**

```
#!/bin/bash

MASTERLOGFILE="$1"
BUILDLOGFILE="$2"
OUTPUTDIFFFILE="$3"

cat $MASTERLOGFILE | cut -d\  -f4-  > $MASTERLOGFILE.1
cat $BUILDLOGFILE | cut -d\  -f4-  > $BUILDLOGFILE.1

vimdiff $MASTERLOGFILE.1 $BUILDLOGFILE.1 -c TOhtml -c  'w! '"$OUTPUTDIFFFILE"'' -c 'qa!'
```

**My Java Test Class that calls the above shell script:**

```
public class GenerateDiffHtml {
    @Test
    public void generateSortedLogFiles() throws Exception {
        try {

            String masterFilePath = "file1.log";
            String buildFilePath = "file2.log";
            String outputDiffFilePath = "result.html";
            String diffScriptPath = "vimDiff.sh";
            Process process = null;
            String[] cmd = {"sh", diffScriptPath, masterFilePath, buildFilePath, outputDiffFilePath};
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            process.waitFor();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Command to run the test:**

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=GenerateDiffHtml
```

Note: The same Java code works fine on a mac machine. So, I wonder if this has something to do with Git Bash on Windows waiting forever, for the process to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running shell scripts in Windows using GitBash. VimDiff is basically a VI editor which requires an action from user. Since you are executing script in background there is no way to perform any action by anyone.

Hence, kindly give it a try by following

1. Remove `process.waitFor();` from your java code.
2. Add commands to remove temp files (.swp or any other) in shell script.